# unable to get fraction of seconds using strptime()

Tags: c++

I am receiving a datetime in YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss[.S+][Z|+-hh:mm] this format. and i m trying to copy that value using `strptime` as shown below

```
struct tm time = {0};
char *pEnd = strptime(datetime, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%Z", &time);
```

But I can't copy the fraction of seconds as `strptime` doesn't support it in C++.

So what should i do?

I found a solution using `gettimeofday()`. but I am already getting date and time in 'datetime' so please help me to find soluntion for it...I can use poco also . but even their we take local time.

Comment: You can count offset in char array and make a sub-string.

Comment: Since `struct tm` does not have a field for [milliseconds]( http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/tm/) strptime will not support fractions of a second in C either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the "S" component from the string before parsing with `strptime`, then use it however you like later (it won't fit anywhere in a Standard `struct tm` - there's no sub-second fields).  Just `datetime.find('.')` and go from there, or use a `regexp` if you prefer - both tedious but not rocket science.

Comment: thank you Tony.But my problem is i ll convert everything in &time to seconds since epoch using ->time_t t = mktime ( &time ). so if i remove S, how should i add it later?.pls help me

Comment: @user3913114 well, it depends what you want to do with your `time_t t`... if you want to get subsecond differences between such values, you can change to `double t = mktime(&time) + s;` or `uint64_t t_ms = mktime(&time) * 1000 + s;` or create a `struct T { time_t t; int ms; };` then you can compare and calculate deltas on such values.  If you want to print the time later in some format, inject the microsecond back in at the appropriate place based on your output function.  If you have some other need and still can't see how to meet it, let us know....

Comment: With time_t t, i will return (t*1000000000L) to the function.100000000L is to convert it it nano seconds.

Comment: @user3913114: well, all simple then... just scale appropriately based on however-many digits S has....

Comment: @user3913114 you're welcome - glad to hear it's sorted.  Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

In C++11 you can use the the high precision timing objects in `<chrono>`, see the answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12835577/how-to-convert-stdchronotime-point-to-calendar-datetime-string-with-fraction).

Comment: Thank you for response. But my problem is i cant take system time or local time. I am already getting the datetime which i ve to represent and sendd it to *pEnd as i shown in above code