# C++ parse date/time with microseconds

Tags: c++, parsing, datetime, posix

I am using `strptime` to parse a date and time with a specific format. The format uses the Python formatting directives, which are exactly the same as the C directives except there is an additional `%f` directive in Python for milliseconds defined as `Microsecond as a decimal number, zero-padded on the left.`. So for example:

```
std::tm tmb;
strptime("2010-12-30T01:20:30.0Z", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ", &tmb);
```

This would cause a parsing error because of the `%f`. I cannot do a straight remove because directives like `%m` and `%d` can take either one or two digits.

Additionally, this is a problem because the `%f` directive can take from 1 to 6 digits. Is there a way to work around this issue?

I am working in C++, if there are any built-in functions that can help.

Comment: Are you trying to keep the sub-second data or simply ignore it?  https://stackoverflow.com/a/25155338/1364178 says you can't store sub-second data in tm.  If you're trying to ignore it, can't you split the string based on the period after seconds?

Comment: You may want not only to thank Howard but to also accept the answer

Answer (score 5):

Using [Howard Hinnant's free, open-source, C++11, header-only datetime library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html), you can easily parse any precision you want.  You just can't put it into a `tm` since that is limited to seconds precision.

For example:

```
#include "date.h"
#include <cassert>
#include <sstream>

int
main()
{
    std::chrono::system_clock::time_point tp;
    std::istringstream ss{"2010-12-30T01:20:30.123456Z"};
    ss >> date::parse("%FT%TZ", tp);
    assert(!ss.fail());
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;
    assert(tp == sys_days(2010_y/dec/30) + 1h + 20min + 30s + 123456us);
}
```

This uses C++14 chrono literals.  If you're in C++11, the last two lines would look like:

```
    using namespace std::chrono;
    assert(tp == sys_days(2010_y/dec/30) + hours{1} + minutes{20} +
                                           seconds{30} + microseconds{123456});
```

If you're stuck with pre-`<chrono>` C++ (C++98/C++03), this library won't help you.

The precision of the parse is controlled by the precision of the `time_point` that you input into the `parse` function, instead of by a formatting flag.  The parse will attempt to parse as many decimal digits as your `time_point` will hold, but will gracefully give up if it gets less digits:

```
sys_time<nanoseconds> tp; // type-alias for a system_clock::time_point
                          //   with nanoseconds precision
ss >> date::parse("%FT%TZ", tp);  // still ok
```

If there are more digits than needed, the parse will fail, but only because it won't see the trailing (required) `Z`:

```
sys_time<milliseconds> tp;
ss >> date::parse("%FT%TZ", tp);
assert(ss.fail());  // found "4" instead of "Z"
```

If the `Z` hadn't been part of the format, it would have parsed `"2010-12-30T01:20:30.123"` into the milliseconds-precsion `time_point`.

This library has complete parsing and formatting facilities available, built on top of the [std `<chrono>` library](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P32hvk8b13M), so that you never have to deal with the ancient `tm` structure.  But you [can convert to/from `tm`](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date/wiki/Examples-and-Recipes#time_point_to_components) (at seconds precision) for communicating with other code if you need to.

`"%F"` is a shortcut for `"%Y-%m-%d"`.  You can use either.

`"%T"` is a shortcut for `"%H:%M:%S"`.  You can use either.

Comment: Thank you for this!

Comment: *The precision of the parse is controlled by the precision of the time_point that you input into the parse function, instead of by a formatting flag*. I had already seen the docs of your library and this comment here has clarified my doubts, because `%T` has here parsed microseconds. A note after `%T` in `from_stream parsing` in the docs may help others. Fantastic library.