# std chrono 1 hour wrong when converting with ctime to char*

Tags: c++, c++11, c++-chrono, ctime

I'm trying to display the difference between high resolution time points in a string like 00:00:00. My problem is that the time is +1 hour when i print it.

```
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;
using namespace chrono;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    auto start = high_resolution_clock::now();
    this_thread::sleep_for(seconds(1));
    auto stop = high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto result = stop - start;
    time_t t = duration_cast<seconds>(result).count();
    cout << ctime(&t) << endl;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

This prints

```
Thu Jan 1 01:00:01 1970
```

While i expect it to print

```
Thu Jan 1 00:00:01 1970
```

Yet the following prints 1:

```
cout << (int) duration_cast<seconds>(result).count() << endl;
```

Maybe it has something to do with the timezone? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I haven't used `ctime` in a while, but [the documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/ctime) seems to indicate the time is converted using `localtime`.

Comment: localtime returns a struct tm*. I could edit the time but i think it should be correct and not adding 1 hour like it does now.

Comment: If you don't want the time zone to be used, then perform the conversion using a function that doesn't use the time zone, perhaps `gmtime` or any of the other alternatives.

Comment: @RetiredNinja woaw, gmtime saves me! i tried and get the expected output, thanks a lot man. Write an answer with it and ill accept it.

Comment: hey @fonZ, I updated my answer.  You should be able to go further with this one.

Answer (score 1):

After discussing in the comments exactly what you were after, I came up with [this](http://ideone.com/ecblE7):

```
size_t MkTimestamp(char *output, size_t size)
{
    milliseconds ms = duration_cast<milliseconds>(system_clock::now().time_since_epoch());
    seconds s = duration_cast<seconds>(ms);
    time_t ctime = (time_t) s.count();
    tm components;
    size_t return_value = 0;

    if (!localtime_r(&ctime, &components)) return 0;
    if ((return_value = strftime(output, size, "%F %T:XXX", &components)) == 0) return 0;

    int ms_d1 = ms.count() / 100 % 10, ms_d2 = ms.count() / 10 % 10, ms_d3 = ms.count() % 10;
    output[return_value - 3] = ms_d1 + '0';
    output[return_value - 2] = ms_d2 + '0';
    output[return_value - 1] = ms_d3 + '0';
    return return_value;
}
```

In short, you give it a character buffer and its size, and it writes a timestamp to it (if the buffer is too small, it returns zero, otherwise it returns the total number of characters it wrote, including the null terminator).  If you wanted this timestamp as a `std::string`, you could use the `std::string` slice constructor:

```
char buffer[64];
string timestamp(buffer, MkTimestamp(buffer, sizeof buffer));
```

The string constructor will read until the null terminator if MkTimestamp succeeds, and will produce an empty string if it fails.  You could probably consolidate this step into `MkTimestamp` if you wanted to.

This is different from your first try in the following way:

- Since you're trying to produce a timestamp, you're better off using absolute, rather than relative, time.
- Since we want to use absolute time, we must use `system_clock`, because this is the only clock that actually gives `time_point` values that can be meaningfully converted into `time_t` values that the old C family functions will accept.  (Sometimes, these two clocks have the same epoch, or are even the same clock.  But not always.)
- I picked a different time format.  You can change that if you want, it won't be hard.  I highly recommend that you keep the millisecond placeholders in the format string, so you don't have to do any length tests as long as `strftime` succeeds.

**Credit where credit is due (other stackoverflow answers that I referenced while writing this answer)**

- [How to convert std::chrono::time_point to calendar datetime string with fractional seconds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12835577/how-to-convert-stdchronotime-point-to-calendar-datetime-string-with-fraction)

**Original answer:**

[Here's an ideone with your code.](http://ideone.com/YT7ArA) (Notice that the issue you describe does not occur.)  Also, you're missing `#include <thread>`.

That aside, the [documentation for `ctime()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/ctime) indicates that its argument is expected to be a calender date.  You're passing it an interval of one second, which is more or less meaningless by itself.  You're probably right that it's showing exactly one hour off because of a time zone interpretation issue.

I can't answer any better without more details about what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: There wasn't one before the edit, when I started writing the answer.

Comment: i know ... but i thought that the people reading this post would understand that this belongs in a program that has a main ... so i added it.

Comment: as for what i'm trying to do, im trying to print a string representation of the elapsed time. 00:00:01 and not 01:00:01. The 1 hour is what is bothering me, because it only 1 second elapsed and the conversion to time_t is legal as far as i know.

Comment: If all you want is elapsed time, then you shouldn't be trying to print it with a function that doesn't handle elapsed times.  Use your second method.

Comment: So for you it prints 00:00:00? On that ideone i see it prints correctly?

Comment: I didn't run it locally.  Why can't you just use `(int) duration_cast<seconds>(result).count()`?

Comment: Because i need a timestamp, i need to show millis micros and nanos, so it would be a long string of numbers to read if we talk about a couple of seconds or even minutes. That's why i'm trying to make it readable.

Comment: Hold on a while and I'll get something working that's closer to what you need.