# Get the Local Time in C++ Visual Studio 2015 Community

Tags: c++, time, visual-studio-2015

I have looked all over for ways to get the current time in C++ for a Console Application project, but every method I have found has been rejected by Visual Studio as incorrect or deprecated, even with #define tags to keep the program from deprecating the functions. What is the current method to get the current time in a Visual Studio C++ Win32 console application?

Comment: what did you try ? GetLocalTime should do it ...

Comment: Please, list at least **every method I have found has been rejected by Visual Studio**

Comment: [`std::chrono::system_clock::now()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/system_clock/now) should do the trick.

Comment: Also be a great idea to edit the question to add in any display formatting requirements you have. πάνταῥεῖ's comment and answer provide the modern C++ solution to get a point in time (`std::chrono::time_point`), but if you want ta time and date string for the user to read, there is [a lot more work coming](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12835577/how-to-convert-stdchronotime-point-to-calendar-datetime-string-with-fraction).

Answer (score 0):

You may use `DateTime::Now`

```
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Globalization;

void main()
{
   DateTime localDate = DateTime::Now;
   array<String^>^ cultureNames = { "en-US", "en-GB", "fr-FR",
                                    "de-DE", "ru-RU" };

   for each (String^ cultureName in cultureNames) {
      CultureInfo^ culture = gcnew CultureInfo(cultureName);
      Console::WriteLine("{0}: {1}", cultureName,
                         localDate.ToString(culture));
   }
}
```

For more information, have a look into [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.now(v=vs.110).aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396&cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-2)

Comment: May be, but not a portable solution unfortunately.

Comment: This solution is not C++. It's C++ with .Net Framework extensions. Not necessarily a bad thing since the stated target is Visual Studio, but users of this solution should be made aware.

Comment: Yes, agree. But if a person who asked the question use the not a portable solution, I think it can help him. if we should found a portable solution, we definetly should see into standard library, for example localtime() routine can help. But I suppose VS 2015 considers this one as a deprecated as well.

Comment: @user4581301 yep, exactly. but seems, it is not a problem for user of VS

Answer (score 0):

Feel free to use this [free, open-source modern C++ library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html):

```
#include "tz.h"
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    std::cout << date::make_zoned(date::current_zone(),
                                  std::chrono::system_clock::now()) << '\n';
}
```

See the installation section for details on how to install this on Windows.  It is known to work with VS-2015.

The library is thread safe and uses no deprecated functionality.  It also does [a lot more things](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vwd3pduVGKY) than just getting the current local time.