# How to format std::chrono durations?

Tags: c++, c++11, string-formatting, c++-chrono

Is there a convenient way to format `std::chrono::duration` to a specified format?

```
std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point now, then;
then = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
// ...
now = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
auto duration = now - then;

// base in microseconds:
auto timeInMicroSec =
      std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(duration);
```

How can I format `timeInMicroSec` like `ss::ms::us`?

Comment: You might want to look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12835577/how-to-convert-stdchronotime-point-to-calendar-datetime-string-with-fraction).

Comment: In addition, Howard Hinnant provided an [outstanding tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P32hvk8b13M) last year at cppcon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can use something like:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>

//...

auto c(timeInMicroSec.count());
std::ostringstream oss;
oss << std::setfill('0')          // set field fill character to '0'
    << (c % 1000000000) / 1000000 // format seconds
    << "::"
    << std::setw(3)               // set width of milliseconds field
    << (c % 1000000) / 1000       // format milliseconds
    << "::"
    << std::setw(3)               // set width of microseconds field
    << c % 1000;                  // format microseconds
auto formatted(oss.str());
```

Answer (score 12):

This takes an arbitrary chrono duration and breaks it down into other duration quantities:

```
template<class...Durations, class DurationIn>
std::tuple<Durations...> break_down_durations( DurationIn d ) {
  std::tuple<Durations...> retval;
  using discard=int[];
  (void)discard{0,(void((
    (std::get<Durations>(retval) = std::chrono::duration_cast<Durations>(d)),
    (d -= std::chrono::duration_cast<DurationIn>(std::get<Durations>(retval)))
  )),0)...};
  return retval;
}
```

Test code:

```
int main() {
  auto then = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  std::this_thread::sleep_for( std::chrono::seconds(3) );
  auto now = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  auto duration = now - then;

  auto clean_duration = break_down_durations<std::chrono::seconds, std::chrono::milliseconds, std::chrono::microseconds>( duration );
  std::cout << std::get<0>(clean_duration).count() << "::" << std::get<1>(clean_duration).count() << "::" << std::get<2>(clean_duration).count() << "\n";
}
```

The formatting code can be cleaned up and put into a function.

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/26041d7303f8d343).

It would be amusing to write an auto-formatters for such a tuple of (increasing precision) durations.

You'd write the outermost duration, then `::`.  After that, you'd convert one unit of the previous duration to the next, take its log based 10, and do a `setw`, and output the next duration.  Repeat until you run out of durations.

I'd probably round-trip this through arrays of `std::size_t` for both `.count()` and for the ratios.

Like this:

```
template<class...Durations>
std::string format_durations( std::tuple<Durations...> d ) {
  std::size_t values[]={(std::size_t)std::get<Durations>(d).count()...};
  auto ratios = get_ratios<Durations...>();

  std::stringstream ss << std::setfill('0');
  ss << values[0];

  for (std::size_t const& v:values) {
    std::size_t i = &v-values;
    if (i==0) continue;
    ss << "::" << std::setw( log_10_round_up(ratios[i-1]) ) << values[i];
  }
  return ss.str();
}
```

with `log_10_round_up` and `get_ratios` to be written.

That lets you take a duration, and format it as hh:mm:ss or whatever else you want.

Comment: Even better in C++17 with structured bindings: `auto [ss, ms, us] = break_down_durations<std::chrono::seconds, std::chrono::milliseconds, std::chrono::microseconds>( duration );`

Comment: Note that the template arguments to `break_down_durations` must be properly ordered according to magnitude and there can be no duplicates.

Comment: @jotik yes, that is true.  Improper orders get you 0s, duplucates give you compile time errors.

Comment: @yisu yes.  To port to 11, write index sequence and replace type based get with index based get.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a possible solution using a variadic template.
The if constexpr () makes it c++17 only but replacing with a regular if still works and is c++14 compliant.

```
template<class DurationIn, class FirstDuration, class...RestDurations>
std::string formatDuration(DurationIn d)
{   
    auto val = std::chrono::duration_cast<FirstDuration>(d);

    string out = std::to_string(val.count());

    if constexpr(sizeof...(RestDurations) > 0) {
        out += "::" + formatDuration<DurationIn, RestDurations...>(d - val);
    }

    return out;
}

template<class DurationIn>
std::string formatDuration(DurationIn) { return {}; } // recursion termination
```

testing in main, outputs "77::600::42"

```
auto formattedStr = formatDuration<
    std::chrono::microseconds,
    std::chrono::seconds,
    std::chrono::milliseconds,
    std::chrono::microseconds>(77'600'042us);
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's the same solution as suggested by @jotik but using the [fmt library](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt) which results in much more compact code:

```
#include <fmt/format.h>

auto c = timeInMicroSec.count();
auto formatted = fmt::format("{}::{:03}::{:03}",
    (c % 1'000'000'000) / 1'000'000, (c % 1'000'000) / 1'000, c % 1'000);
```